# Uploading file Azure Clound Service WebRole gives me an error: Access to path denied

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application running as an Azure Cloud Service WebRole and I need to b able to upload files to my /Views/Whatever directory so I can quickly edit files on the fly without having to re-publish which can take 30 minutes.

How can I set the permissions to allow me to save files to this path?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single instance Web Role (which I assume it would be, I can't imagine you editing files on each one of the instances), then you can just enable Web Deploy on your deployment and be done. Then you can use Web Deploy to send the updates to your site without having to RDP. Just keep in mind that if for whatever reason the machine has to be moved or re-imaged (e.g. host updates) you'll lose your changes if they are not part of the Cloud Package (cspkg).

You can enable the option as part of the deployment of your Cloud Service.